# Proper way to use caching of sql.Array in MyBatis

Tags: java, postgresql, caching, jdbc, mybatis

Following this topic in [PostgreSQL JDBC driver](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/726) I'm looking for an elegant way to leverage MyBatis build-in caching capabilities for `ResultSet` containing an [sql.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html).

Excerpt of [MyBatis documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache):

> A read-write cache will return a copy (via serialization) of the cached object.

Since MyBatis can only cache objects which implements `Serializable` Interface and neither `sql.Array` interface does extend it nor `PgArray` in my particular case does implement it, MyBatis throws
`org.apache.ibatis.cache.CacheException: Error serializing object. Cause: java.io.NotSerializableException` when querying for a `ResultSet` containing an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) or result of [array_agg() function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

What would be the preferred way to achieve caching in this scenario?

Can I use [javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialArray.html) in combination with [MyBatis ResultMap collection or association](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps)?

e.g.

```
<association property="values" column="myArrayColumn" javaType="ArrayList"  jdbcType ="SerialArray"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, a column in your result set is of type SQL Array.
And you want to execute the same query with same parameters multiple times in the session, actually hit the Database the first time and afterward hit the cache.

Mybatis association is used to map flat result row to object structure.
Mybatis collection purpose is to map multiple result rows nested in an object (e.g: select parent and children).
both of them are not appliable here.
Here this an array/collection of element, but inline in a column for each row.

You must not bother with caching SQL Array: you must map it to the result type and forget it.

Then extend `org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler`:

```
@Override
public final Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final String columnName) throws SQLException {
    LOGGER.debug("getNullableResult - resultSet/columnName");
    final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnName);
    return array.getArray();
}

@Override
public final Object getNullableResult(final ResultSet resultSet, final int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    LOGGER.debug("getNullableResult - resultSet/columnIndex");
    final Array array = resultSet.getArray(columnIndex);
    return array.getArray();
}
```

Here returned value is a basic java Array, but you may a List or build whatever structure you want.

Reference the type handler to be used in the resultMap:
`<result column="arrayColumnName" property="destinationProperty" typeHandler="yourArrayTypeHandlerClass.fullQualifiedName" />`

The SQL Array cannot be serializable: this is a resource: it depends on the *ResultSet* that is closed after it is fetched and depending on the *PreparedStatement* closed as well.

The result that is cached is a collection of object of the result type mapped, that shall be serializable.